# Group of data in shell language

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wonder if the data in the group aren’t numbers ; the script works?

When `x="1 2 3"` I can do a for loop:

```
for i in $x
```

I wonder if this is correct :

```
    read x
    read y

    xm=`cat $x`
    ym=`cat $y`
    zm="$xm $ym"
    for i in $zm
    do

      for j in $i 
      do 
         echo $j
     done
done
```

Comment: I don't, at all, understand the question. `for i in <list>` loops over the list of words in `<list>` they do not need to be numbers (and if they are numbers they will not be interpreted as a range or anything).

Comment: i meant that can i merge the content of files and put them into a list like this zm="$xm $ym" for i in $zm ;do for j in $i do echo $j ..

Comment: You don't need `zm` for anything here but yes if you want to loop over the words in each of the two files you could do that. You could also just call `cat "$x" "$y"` once since it takes multiple files. That being said you **should not** read lines/words from files this way. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for why not and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
x="1 2 3"
for i in $x
```

what you are doing is `for i in 1 2 3:`.

But in second case doing

```
xm=`cat $x`
ym=`cat $y`
```

This might lead to error saying `No such file or directory` is the `echo $x` and `echo $y` file does not exit. It will also give error saying if is directory.

Even if that works, then loop will go through each and every word of the file `echo $x` and `echo $y`.

Example for second case:

filename: 2

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Now doing:

```
ym=`cat 2`
for i in $ym; do echo $i; done
```

output:

```
The
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog.
```

If the content of file is: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`, the output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

---

If you do:

```
for i in "$xm $ym"; do ....; done
```

it will take `"$xm $ym"` as a whole.

If you are wishing to do take each word individually from both file, use:

```
for i in $xm $ym; do ....; done
```

Example:

assume two file:

`file1` and `file2`.
Content of file1 is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, and that of file2 is: `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`

Now:

```
xm=`cat file1`
ym=`cat file2`
```

---

```
j=0
for i in "$xm $ym";do echo $i  $j; ((j+=1)); done
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 0
```

---

```
j=0
for i in $xm $ym;do echo $i  $j; ((j+=1)); done
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
The 10
quick 11
brown 12
fox 13
jumps 14
over 15
the 16
lazy 17
dog. 18
```

---

I hope now it is clear.

Comment: i meant that can i merge the content of  files and put them into a list like this `zm="$xm $ym" ` 
`for i in $zm ;do for j in $i do echo $j ..`